# create main directory with folders inside and specific sub-folders

Tags: shell, mkdir

In the code below I create a main directory using the`$DATE` variable and create 5 folders in that directory. What I can not seem to figure out is how to create sub-folders in specific folders.  Thank you :).

```
DATE=`date +%-m-%-d-%Y` 
mkdir -p /home/Desktop/$DATE/{validation,file,test,count,base}
```

**structure example**

```
6-1-2016 (`directory`)
validation  file    test    count     base (`folders`)
-1 -2                      -1 -2 -3   -1  (`sub-folders within folder`)
```

update: The below will create a directory by date followed by 5 folders in that directory, with 1 sub-folder in validation.  However, I can only seem to create one sub-folder and not multiple.  Thank you :).

```
DATE=`date +%-m-%-d-%Y` 
mkdir -p /home/Desktop/$DATE/{validation/1,file,test,count,base}
```

**file structure**

```
6-1-2016 (`directory`)
validation  file    test    count   base (`folders`)
- 1                                      (`sub-folders within folder`)
```

Comment: It's not `mkdir` that does the path expansion, it's the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar question, this works:

```
DATE=`date +%-m-%-d-%Y`
mkdir -p /home/Desktop/$DATE/{validation/{-1},file,test,count/{1,2,3},base/{1}}
```

**output** (directory by date
                folder
                   sub-folder (within each specific folder)

```
6-2-2016
validation     file     test      count       base
-1                               -1 -2 -3     -1
```